# Synergy: Connection failed to connect to server: incompatible client 1.3

Tags: synergy

I have installed synergy 1.5 on a RHEL6 server (panther) and Xubuntu 13.10 (wolf). My synergy.conf file is

```
section: options
    screenSaverSync = true
end
section: screens
    panther:
    wolf:
end
section: links
    panther:
    right = wolf
   wolf:
       left = panther
end
```

As a non-root user on panther I start the server

```
synergys --config /etc/synergy.conf
```

and get the following message

```
INFO: Synergy 1.5.0 Server on Linux 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 20 12:17:37 EST 2013 x86_64
```

However when I run `synergyc -f panther` on the client machine

```
NOTE: connecting to panther: 172.31.70.161:24800
WARNING: failed to connect to server: incompatible client 1.3
```

I get the same error when substituting panther with the ip and also with iptables disabled on the server.

Any ideas

Answer (score 4):

Synergy requires the same version on both the server and the client. See:

http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/trouble.html#problem8

While you write that use have install 1.5 on both machines. The 1.3 in the error message suggests you may have just installed synergy from the Ubuntu repositories as they were most likely shipping a 1.3 version with 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

For me, all I had to do was upgrade Synergy on both machines, and then restart the daemon processes:

```
sudo ps aux | grep -i synergy
```

and then whatever `pid` you see (e.g., if it is 77279),

```
kill 77279
```